# Is it safe to start a Task from ContinueWith method of the same task?

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, task, task-parallel-library

I have a windows service with a listener that runs a loop within a task that listens to ServiceBus. If the connection goes down or some other problem occurs I want to start the listener task again. Since I do not do any await on the task as it is should run forever I do need to use ContinueWith and check if the exception has occurred. If it did I want to start exactly the same process.

So the question is: Is it safe to do it this way with regards to execution context, memory, stack trace or some other things I have not thought about?

The code seems to run all fine and reconnects if the network was down and came back online, stack trace for the exceptions seems correct as well but I am afraid of some pitfalls I have not thought about.

```
private void StartReceiving(string connectionString)
{
    _receiverHost
        .StartReceiving(connectionString)
        .ContinueWith(c =>
        {
            if (c.IsFaulted)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(60000);
                StartReceiving(connectionString);
            }
        }
    });
```

}

Comment: Why do that at all? Use `async/await` instead. If you want to implement retry logic sleeping like that won't help either - you just froze a *threadpool thread* for 1 minute. And you may freeze another if the call keeps failing

Comment: It's a *lot* easier to retry when using asynchronous code. You can use `await` inside a loop that retries the call up to eg 3 times. Catch the appropriate exceptions inside the loop to retry. Even better, use a library like Polly that allows you to specify the retry, delay policies without polluting your code

Comment: Freezing the threadpool thread for 1 minute is what I want in this case. There are already required retries in the loop, what I want to handle that if e.g. network goes down and everything crashes, the app tries to reconnect once a minute and start the whole pipeline again. I have few parallel tasks like that that are running and it's possible that one of the loses connection to the server

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik Blocking a thread pool thread is just pointless and unproductive.  It's better to just *not have any thread doing anything at all* for that time, and schedule the thread pool thread to run the method *after the time has elapsed* rather than forcing your thread pool threads to sit there and not do anything productive when they could instead be off doing useful work (or perhaps allowing the thread pool to have fewer threads in it, reducing the system resources consumed).

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik you don't want to freeze the thread - that only helps to create a bottleneck. You want to *delay before retrying*

Comment: @Servy Yes, that seems like a good point, I suppose Task.Delay() or something like that would be a better option

Comment: You still haven't addresses Pantagiotis's initial comment asking why you aren't using async/await.

Comment: I don't use async/await because it's a task that runs all the time. And I start a number of these listeners, so await will be quite pointless, since it will just not allow me to do anything else before an infinite loop finishes.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik `await` is just syntactic sugar that allows you to add continuations to a task, but in such a way that it's easier to write, has better defaults, and interacts more effectively with other language features.  In particular, it makes proper error handling *much* easier.  Using `await` here would simply allow you to write *functional identical code* that simply happens to have a syntax that more closely resembles synchronous code.

Comment: @Servy I do use async/await every other place in code and agree that it is superior. The problem is that I cannot use an await on a task that runs an infinite loop (I have more than one of these) unless I do not understand something?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik The operation *doesn't* run in an infinite loop.  It loops until it succeeds, which is only infinitely if it never succeeds.  But you're talking about awaiting *this operation*, not *using await in the implementation of this operation*.  Both can be appropriate.

Comment: @Servy I am not quite sure how do you suggest to use await on the top level because it should never succeed (it can only fail)? I do use await in the implementation. Maybe you can point me in the right direction?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik Sure, it can only fail, and any time you want to know when a given asynchronous operation has completed, whether successfully or not, you can await it.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

> "Is it safe to do it this way with regards to execution context, memory, stack trace or some other things I have not thought about?"

Yes; there is no issues in regards of any of the mentioned areas that i can think of.
You basically exit the previous task and enter a new task. Your memory is cleaned when you continue the following task and the stacktrace is starting at the task creating the execution.

However I'd rather comment on the issues it introduces in regards of error handling and breaking the execution, which by this implementation does not help you to find the error, connect to an alternative address or some other logic you may introduce. In my opinion you introduce an unexpected complexity in this implementation.

If I had to implement this class, I would rather raise a disconnected event which the class using this object has to solve. This will give you a much wider range of opportunities, e.g. notifying other dependent classes.

Furthermore, freezing a thread is usually not a good solution. I'd rather start a timer or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in some extra code as follows, and I wasn't able to see any issue with execution context, memory, stack trace.

```
public class Receiver
{
    public async Task StartReceiving(string connectionString)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                throw new Exception("connection lost");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                /* log the exception, or something */
                throw;
            }
        });
        await task;
    }
}

public class Server
{
    ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger<Server>();

    public bool IsStopped { get; private set; } = false;
    private Receiver _receiverHost = new Receiver();
    public void StartReceiving(string connectionString)
    {
        _receiverHost
            .StartReceiving(connectionString)
            .ContinueWith(async c =>
            {
                if (c.IsFaulted)
                {
                    var n = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count;
                    var timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    log.Debug($"Task Delay: {(DateTime.UtcNow - timestamp).TotalSeconds} seconds");
                    StartReceiving(connectionString);
                }
            });
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class TestServerRetry
{
    [TestCase]
    public async Task TestRetry()
    {
        var server = new Server();
        server.StartReceiving("test connection");
        while (!server.IsStopped)
            await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `Task` constructor, favor instead: true async methods (IO bound) or `Tas.Run` (CPU bound). Also, you're not awaiting that `Task.Delay` so the `while` loop is free to spin. P.s. Not the downvoter.

Comment: Thanks, I have not seen any problems myself, but that does not mean that some hidden gimmick does not exist :)

Comment: Thank you, @JSteward. As you pointed out, I added await for `Task.Delay` inside the `ContinueWith` method's lambda, and for `Task.Delay` in `TestRetry` method, I added `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. and, I replaced `new Task` with `Task.Run`. I ran it with some additional code to log the delayed time, and could confirm now it is actually delayed. Thanks again for your kind correction :)

Comment: You can drop the `task.Start()` and, looks like your using xUnit which supports async tests when marked `async Task` so you could drop the `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` but +1

Comment: oh, yes. Thank you. I forgot to delete that line. I'm using NUnit and found that NUnit also supports async tests. I updated the code. Thanks for your help! and thanks for +1